# Is this query possible in nosql (with mongodb)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I use mongoose in my node.js app, and basically have the following models:

```
// Define Car model
CarSchema = new Schema({
  brand  : String,
  type: String,    
  maxSpeed : Number
});
mongoose.model('Car', CarSchema);
// Define User model
UserSchema = new Schema({
  lastname        : String,
  firstname : String,
  cars   : [CarSchema]
});
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I'm really new to NoSQL and I really want to give it a try but I first need to study if this really fits my needs.

With the above models, will I be able to create a query listing all the Users who have a particular type of car among their personal cars ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't how to do it in mongoose. But in mongodb it possible. So, in mongodb shell query will looks like this:

```
db.users.find({"cars.type":"sport"})
```

Above query return all users thats have car with type 'sport' in their nested collection of cars.

Mongodb [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) documentation.

Comment: do you know a main to filter on the last items of the cars list ? I have submitted another question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627995/mongoose-node-js-query-with-lt-and-gt-not-working and I cannot find the answer.