# mongoose node.js, query with $lt and $gt not working

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I want to get all the pupils whose last mark is between 15 and 20. To do so, I perform the following query in my mongoDB using mongoose:
The models are working fine (all the other queries are ok).

```
Pupils.find({"marks[-1].value": {'$lt' : 20 }, "marks[-1].value" : { '$gt' : 15 }}, function(err, things){
```

This is not working, is there something I missed ?

*** UPDATE ***

I found something like:

```
Pupils.find({ "marks[-1].value": {$gt : 15, $lt : 20}});
```

But this does not work either. Is there a way to get the last mark of the marks array in this case ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets consider your `Pupils` collection:

```
Pupils 
{
  _id,
  Marks(integer),
  LatestMark(int)
}
```

I suggest to add latest mark into Pupil document(as you can see at the document above), and update it each time when you adding new mark into nested collection.
Then you will able to query on it like this:

```
db.Pupils.find({ "LatestMark": {$gt : 15, $lt : 20}});
```

Also you can query latest mark using [$where](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D), but be care because:

> Javascript executes more slowly than
>   the native operators, but is very flexible

Comment: I was also thinking about going in this direction but did not really know if this was the right way. You convinced me :) Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Luc: Don't care when adding extra field, mongodb perfect fit for denormalization( and any document database in general).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not working because the embedded collections in mongo are accessed like this:
"marks.0.value", although I haven't used mongoose.

Unfortunately for your scenario, I do not think there is a way to use negative indexing. (Mongo doesn't guarantee a preserved natural order unless you use a capped collection anyway though)

You may be able to accomplish this using Map/Reduce or a group command

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

Comment: do you tnink there is a way to get only the last elements of marks ?

Answer (score -1):

**This is tip than an answer.**

Use double quotes for special key words like **$elemMatch, $get, $lt** etc while using **mangoose**.

In following code,$gt will **not work** properly.

```
    var elmatch = { companyname: mycompany };
    var condition = { company_info: { $elemMatch: elmatch } };

    if(isValid(last_id)){
        condition._id = { $gt: new ObjectId(last_id) };
    }
    console.log(condition);

    User.find(condition).limit(limit).sort({_id: 1}).exec(function (err, lists) {
        if (!err) {
            res.send(lists);
            res.end();
        }else{
            res.send(err);
            res.end();

        }
    });
```

But this **issue is solved** when i'm using **double quotes** for special keywords

```
    var elmatch = { companyname: mycompany };
    var condition = { company_info: { "$elemMatch": elmatch } };

    if(isValid(last_id)){
        condition._id = { "$gt": new ObjectId(last_id) };
    }
    console.log(condition);

    User.find(condition).limit(limit).sort({_id: 1}).exec(function (err, lists) {
        if (!err) {
            res.send(lists);
            res.end();
        }else{
            res.send(err);
            res.end();

        }
    });
```

I hope it will be helpful.